# Ruby-aware completion using neocomplcache in vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, neocomplcache

Suppose I'm writing a custom validation method in a Rails model:

```
validate :customer_must_be_valid
```

And then I'm writing this method for validation:

```
def cust<TAB>
```

And neocomplcache does not present me with the completion for `customer_must_be_valid`.

Basically the problem is that symbols are not treated as possible method names when doing completion. How can I fix this?

For reference, here's my [vimrc](https://github.com/pjg/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc).

#### UPDATE

When pressing <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> it doesn't show, but when I press <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> it **does** show me the completion for the method name.

Comment: What happens if you hit `<C-x><C-o>`?

Comment: NeoComplCache only provides the "auto" part of "autocompletion". The "completion" part is handled by scripts, default or custom. Make sure the default omnicompletion works reliably first.

Comment: The question still stands :) I don't know how to fix it :/ For all I know it might be my vimrc, it might be some setting that needs to be set, it might be neocomplcache...

Comment: You don't need to set anything beside `ftplugin indent on` in your `~/.vimrc` for omnicompletion to work. "Better", "good" or "IDE-like" omnicompletion for your language may require additional plugins and additional settings. Since I don't do Ruby I can't help you further. That error message when trying `<C-x><C-o>` suggests that the default Ruby omnicompletion script can't handle that situation so you should look around for an alternative script. And do your tests *without* NeoComplCache, by the way.